# Определить шифт по Оси Х ( css / js ). 5-ый класс, геометрия

Tags: javascript, css, graphics, math

Пытаюсь нарисовать что то типа звёздочки *.

https://jsfiddle.net/jsfiddlefcn/w7y86acz/7/

От центра `width / 2` и `height / 2` и в разные точки `bx` и `by`.

```
var counter = 0;

function linedraw(ax, ay, bx, by) {
  var r = parseInt(Math.random() * 255);
  var g = parseInt(Math.random() * 255);
  var b = parseInt(Math.random() * 255);
  var a = 0.45;
  var caty = Math.abs(ay - by);
  var catx = Math.abs(ax - bx);
  counter++;
  /*
  $("<div id='catx" + counter + "'>").css({ // optional.
    "height": '2px',
    "background": 'rgba(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ',' + a + ')',
    "width": catx,
    "position": "absolute",
    "top": by,
    "left": Math.min(ax, bx),
    // "transform": "rotate("+rotation+"deg)"
  }).appendTo("#body");
  $("<div id='caty" + counter + "'>").css({ // optional.
    "height": '2px',
    "background": 'rgba(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ',' + a + ')',
    "width": caty,
    "position": "absolute",
    "top": Math.min(ay, by) + caty / 2,
    "left": bx - caty / 2,
    "transform": "rotate(90deg)"
  }).appendTo("#body");*/
  var width = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(catx, 2) + Math.pow(caty, 2));
  var atan = Math.atan( (ay-by) / (ax - bx) );
  //var acos = Math.acos(caty / width);
  //var asin = Math.asin(catx / width);
  var rotation = atan * 360 / ( 2 * Math.PI );
  //var rotation = acos * 360 / ( 2 * Math.PI );
  //var rotation = asin * 360 / ( 2 * Math.PI );
  var Y = Math.min(ay, by) + caty / 2;
  var X = Math.min(ax, bx);
  $("<div id='diagonal_" + counter + "'>").css({ // Main Line
    "height": '2px',
    "background": 'rgba(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ',' + a + ')',
    "width": width,
    "position": "absolute",
    "top": Y,
    "left": X,
    "transform": "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)"
  }).appendTo("#body");
}

var height = 500;
var width = 500;
var step = 30;
for (var x = 0; x < width; x += step) {
  for (var y = 0; y < height; y += step) {
    linedraw(width / 2, height / 2, x, y);
  }
}
```

**`rotation` и `Y` - УЖЕ ПРАВИЛЬНЫЕ!**

Нужно определить шифт по Оси-Х.

Переменная

```
"left": X,
```

Все линии немного сдвигаются вправо по Оси-Х, в зависимости от угла с Осью-Х. Чем больше угол - тем больше НЕИЗВЕСТНЫЙ сдвиг.

[JPEG example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMb8V.jpg)

Comment: Вам именно на `html+css` нужно? С помощью `canvas` это проще можно сделать.

Comment: нет, canvas не нужно, нужны правильные `X`, `Y` и `rotation` для наклонной диагонали.

Comment: Заглянул в ДОМ - офигел.

Comment: @VostokSisters, подскажи, пожалуйста, как мне заглянуть в ДОМ?

Comment: @jsfiddlefcn, ПКМ - "Посмотреть код".

Comment: думаю, transform-origin поможет

Comment: http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/OpmNbO  я вот захотел крест нарисовать и использовал svg и получилось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По шагам пожалуй расскажу...

1. Для начала надо поставить X в точку ax.

Это будет хорошей(а может быть и единственно правильной) точкой отсчета.

```
X = ax;
```

2. Теперь о случайном характере смещения.

У всех элементов разная длина, но совпадает левый угол, если их начать вращать вокруг этого угла,
то они образуют веер с одним центром, но css не вращает элементы вокруг угла (по дефолту),
он вращает их вокруг центра, а из-за разной длины у них центры находятся в разных точках.
Так что получается некоторое смещение, зависящее от местонахождения центра.
Центр несложно найти: width / 2, то есть каждый элемент смещается на width / 2;

```
X = ax - width/2
//(если скомпилировать код, то теперь все полоски как бы нанизаны на центр)
```

3.
Теперь все полоски выстроились в шеренгу, но они не расположились по кругу.
Они смещены на половину ширины своего катета (потому, что вертятся вокруг центра), это несложно исправить:

```
X = ax - width/2 + catx/2
//(если скомпилировать код и внимательно вглядеться, можно увидеть что половина полосок уже растет из середины, а вторая сместилась еще сильнее)
```

4.
Чтобы определить смещение им надо знать длину катета, иногда она положительна, значит при вращении точка, которая должна быть в центре веера, сместилась влево;
иногда длина отрицательна, значит точка сместилась вправо, однако к тому моменту когда оно начинает вычислять, катет уже приведен к модулю и всегда положителен,
чтож просто добавим проверку:

```
if (bx > ax)
  var X = ax - width/2 + catx/2;
  else
  var X = ax - width/2 - catx/2;
```

Comment: большое, человеческое спасибо!

Comment: Нашёл ещё более изящный способ, без `if / else`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5912283/7695224